# Jquery datatable child table Page length dropdown not clickable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTable to make a grid. Actually I want to have two, first one is the parent grid, and 2nd one is it's child grid. First grid loads fine. It contains a plus (+) button per row, if user clicks it then it's child grid will be shown. In child grid page length option is not working. I don't know why when I click it to change the page length, the dropDown it's not clickable. Below is my code. Please help me.

Here is my Parent table

```
table = $('#resolvedTable').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "paging": true,
        "order": [1, 'desc'],
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/Controller/Action?fromDate=' + $("#FromDate").val() + '&toDate=' + $("#ToDate").val(),
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                data: null,
                sortable: false,
                className: 'details-control',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<button class="showhidebtn collapsed details-control" data-toggle="collapse" style="width:10px ; height 10px;"></button>';
                }
            },
            { "name": "Name", "data": "Name" },
            { "name": "Count1", "data": "Count1" },
            { "name": "Count2", "data": "Count2" },
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]]
    });
```

Here is the function when I click on plus (+) button to show 2nd table (grid):

```
$('#resolvedLeadTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);
        var rowdata = table.row(tr).data();
        GetChildTable(rowdata.Id, rowdata.OrginId, table.row(tr).index())
    });
```

Here is my child table (grid) code:

```
function GetChildTable(Id, OriginId, rowIndex) {
    if (typeof table.row(rowIndex).child() == "undefined") {
        var data = [
        { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" }, { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" },
        { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" }, { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" },
        { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" }, { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" },
        { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" }, { "Name": "test", "StatusName": "test 1", "OriginName": "test 12" }]
        var obj = data;
        var agentDetailsBody = "";
        $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
            agentDetailsBody += "<tr><td>" + val.LeadName + "</td><td>" + val.LeadStatusName + "</td><td>" + val.LeadOriginName + "</td> </tr>"
        });

        $('#agentDetailsBody').html(agentDetailsBody);
        var $table = $($('#HtmlEncodeForAgentDetails').html().replace("agentDetailsBody", "agentDetailsBody-" + rowIndex));
        $table.css('width', '100%');
        var childTable = $table.DataTable({
            "ordering": true,
            "paging": true,
            "info": false,
            "searching": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "columns": [
                { "name": "Col 1" },
                { "name": "Col 2" },
                { "name": "Col 3" },
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]]
        });

        table.row(rowIndex).child(childTable.table().container()).show()
    }
    else {
        table.row(rowIndex).child().toggle();
    }
}
```

Please, could you tell me what's wrong in my code? Why page length is not working in child table?

Comment: A snippet would help

Comment: Could you include your HTML code, please? It's not quite clear to me what's "HtmlEncodeForAgentDetails", for example.